# Delete Core Data for Entity in Swift 2

Tags: swift, core-data

How do you delete all the entries in Core Data for an entity, in Swift?

I want to have a deleteAll() method, so that I can clear the database.

This is what I have so far:

```
func deleteAllCoreData() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DataPoint")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
        try coordinator.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: managedContext)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

But it has an error:

> Unknown command type  (entity: DataPoint; predicate:
>   ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type:
>   NSManagedObjectIDResultType; ) >

Answer (score 1):

iOS 9 added a new class called NSBatchDeleteRequest that allows you to easily delete objects matching a predicate without having to load them all in to memory. Here's how you'd use it:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Foo")
let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

do {
    //`myPersistentStoreCoordinator` is from the core data stack
    try myPersistentStoreCoordinator.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: myContext)
} catch let error as NSError {
    // TODO: handle the error
}
```

Comment: Updated my question, still has some bug. But I think i'm close.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, http://www.learncoredata.com/nsbatchdeleterequest-in-ios-9/, maybe you will find it useful.

Comment: My app is for OS X. I am not sure that NSBatchDeleteRequest is available for OS X.

Comment: It seems that it available for OS X too. Look closely at `NSBatchDeleteRequest` header file (ObjC), and you will see next class macro - `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_11,9_0)`.